# "No viable alternative at input" on custom JPQL queries error after migrating from Hibernate JPA 2.2.4 to 3.1.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is my custom defined JPA query, it was working fine on Hibernate 5.x but I have to upgrade Spring and it's related packages to LTS, so after migrating to Hibernate 6.x the below query is throwing the error of "No viable alternative at input".

The query being parsed with no whitespaces so the final query becomes "selectipfromInsurancePlanipleftouterjoinFacilityLocationflonip.facilityLocation.id=fl.idwhereip.name=:fesdfesand(fl.id=:safasf3r1orip.isSystemDefaultistrue" which is erroneous, look at the detailed error at the end.

```
@Query("select ip from InsurancePlan ip left outer join FacilityLocation fl on ip.facilityLocation.id=fl.id " +
        "where ip.name = :name and (fl.id = :facilityLocationId or ip.isSystemDefault is true)")
Optional<InsurancePlan> doesInsurancePlanWithNameExistInDefaultOrCustomPlans(@Param(value = "name") String name,
                                                                             @Param(value = "facilityLocationId") Integer facilityLocationId);
```

Error Details:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [select ip from InsurancePlan ip left outer join FacilityLocation fl on ip.facilityLocation.id=fl.id where ip.name = :fesdfes and (fl.id = :safasf3r1 or ip.isSystemDefault is true)]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:795)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy159.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [select ip from InsurancePlan ip left outer join FacilityLocation fl on ip.facilityLocation.id=fl.id where ip.name = :fesdfes and (fl.id = :safasf3r1 or ip.isSystemDefault is true)]
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.parseHql(StandardHqlTranslator.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$interpretHql$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:741)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:786)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:174 no viable alternative at input 'selectipfromInsurancePlanipleftouterjoinFacilityLocationflonip.facilityLocation.id=fl.idwhereip.name=:fesdfesand(fl.id=:safasf3r1orip.isSystemDefaultistrue'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator$1.syntaxError(StandardHqlTranslator.java:46)
```

Comment: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/query-parser-removes-whitespaces-from-hql-after-upgrade-to-6-1-x/7080 - I guess it is an issue with `ip.isSystemDefault is true`. You can try to use `ip.isSystemDefault = 1`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer the linked article says that earlier versions of hibernate allowed using of "true" as parameter so ":true"(param) won't work now because it might be reserved and new param names should be used, I have already read that article and tried using your proposed solution too, plus tried changing  my param names too, but nothing worked.